# How query two different Sum from the same table for the same column but with different condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, case

I would like to fetch the sum of field TOTAL for active users and sum of field TOTAL for inactive users.

```
id userId active total
 1 1         1     10
 2 1         1     5
 3 1         0     30
 4 1         0     20
```

Expecting is the query that results activeTotal = 15 and InactiveTotal = 50

**SELECT SUM(actUser.total) as activeTotal, SUM(inActUser.total) as inactiveTotal
FROM user actUser
JOIN user inActUser ON inActUser.id = inActUser.id
WHERE (actUser.active = 1 AND actUser.userId = 1) OR (inActUser.active = 0 AND inActUser.userId= 1)**

But I am not getting the expected result....I am getting the same number for inactive user as getting for inactive users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case when active = 1 then total else 0 end) total_active,
    sum(case when active = 0 then total else 0 end) total_inactive
from mytable
```

If you have just `0`s and `1`s in column `active`, we can simplify:

```
select
    sum(active * total) total_active,
    sum( (1 - active) * total) total_inactive
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks...It helped me to achieve what I was looking for.